# How does PHP website communicate with Java and C# programs efficiently

Tags: c#, java, php, web, interop

I have a website written in PHP, the website accepts code snippets written in different programming languages (Java and C#) and perform some static analysis and returns the results to the user. I already wrote different analyzers for Java and C# respectively. The Java analyzer is written in Java; the C# analyzer is written in C#.

My problem is how the PHP website can communicate with those analyzers written in different languages in an efficient way. That is: when the PHP website receives some Java code, it can invokes the Java analyzer, etc. I can of course use PHP’s exec to launch the analyzer process, but that is too slow.

Comment: Can the server hosting the PHP pages support Java Server Pages and ASP.Net pages?

Comment: This scheme does not work if I want to support other languages.

Comment: Can you give some timing examples?  What does *too slow* mean?  How long do the analyzers take when run directly from the command-line? vs. run from the PHP page?  If you could eliminate all the overhead time from piping through PHP exec, would it then be "fast enough"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Web Services, because they are easy to develop, extensible, scalable, plataform independant, and language independant, and supports standard http protocols; not sure if you will use all the advantages that SOA offers, and probably it's not the best approach, but i would go for it.

Hope it helps.

[Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)

[Web Services Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp)

Comment: How do I host those services? One for Java and one for C#? Is there a server which can host services in different languages. I'm new to web service, so may be the questions are quite naive.

Comment: @jasonweiyi you can host WCF's in IIS. not sure about java (apache?)

Comment: Indeed @Bahamut, however, it's not important, you can host them anywhere, because a Web Service works with standard http protocol, you can even host them in different servers, in different countries and it would still work. I don't know of any server which can host different applications, there are some services, like heroku, that supports different languages, but not C#

Comment: @fer13488 I know. I thought he was referring to the counterpart of IIS to host java or other type of web service. All web service requests still look the same even if they're different languages.

to jasonweiyi, Are you asking about trying to host both in one machine? You could use a virtual machine in that case. I've only worked with WCFs so I don't have much of an idea with IIS's counterparts on other languages.

Comment: It is best for me to host all services on one machine because this keeps the cost low. As I understand from all the above helpful suggestions, I should use a Windows machine because it support C# services. 

I am not sure which of the solution is better: (1) run different servers on the windows machine (one for java, one for python for future) (2) use dedicated virtual machines which all run on top of the window host, and each virtual machine handles a particular language.

I want to use solution (1), but solution (2) seems easier if later I want to use real servers to handle languages.

Comment: Forget servers, I would go for a Cloud app hosting, you could host any application without thinking about servers, as far as i understand this hosting supports Java, C#, python, ruby, etc, (http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_faq/), so i'm sure that there are more cloud hosting providers

Comment: According to the pricing from rackspace: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/public/servers/pricing/, Cloud app hosting is much more expensive than dedicated server renting: http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produktmatrix/rootserver-produktmatrix-ex

Comment: @jasonweiyi you're right, but, that's because cloud hosting is focused in running lightweight apps, like webservices, big heavy apps are outdated, the new technologies are moving to the cloud, because it's more stable, reliable, and can handle lots of concurrent connections with minimum resources, because the cloud architecture ,by definition, is tougth for distributed computing, you will only need the basic plan, but maybe it's not what you want, it was just a suggestion, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For C# i would host it as Windows service and then setup a self hosted WCF service configured for REST. The webserver (PHP) would then communicate using REST

I guess you could do something similar with the Java program, but I do not know how to run it as a service

Comment: I thought about running a java web server, but this means for each language I add in the future, I have to add a separate server for it.

Comment: Yeah even two is too much. Port the Java code to C# and then create a .NET Backend which serves all logic for the site.